# Using Applescript and Javascript: get checkbox IDs from webpage, loop over, if end matches string click checkbox

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I'm trying to use applescript and javascript to click all the checkboxes on https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect whos element IDs end with the relevant domain.
ElementID example is "person@domain.com"

This works when you know the exact ID and can specify it first:

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect"
    delay 3
    do JavaScript "
    document.getElementById('person@domain.com').click();
    " in document 1
end tell
```

This is a recycled attempt at trying to loop:

```
to goToWebPage(theWebPage)
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        set URL of document 1 to theWebPage
    end tell
end goToWebPage

to clickID(theId) --creates a function that we can use over and over again instead of writing this code over and over again

    tell application "Safari" -- lets AppleScript know what program to controll

        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click();" in document 1 -- performs JavaScript code that clicks on the element of a specific id

    end tell -- tells Applescript you are done talking to Safari

end clickID -- lets AppleScript know we are done with the function

goToWebPage("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect")
clickID("person@domain.com")
```

based on the example: http://www.cubemg.com/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-with-applescript/

Basically the list of calendars to sync will change so I would like to make an array/list of all the checkbox IDs. 
Loop through them, if any of the IDs ends with domain.com.
click that box.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the URL to the page in question, that's very important and usually very helpful. In my case, I only have my own calendar, which doesn't make for a very good means to test things out on. Could you copy and paste the HTML source code from yours ?  You can omit the entire `<head>...</head>` section, but the `<body>...</body>` HTML would be very helpful. Essentially, what you're asking is simple to do (but not the way you describe), but can't script it with the one-checkbox I have on my page.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution this morning thanks for the documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect"
    delay 3
    do JavaScript "

    var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    for (var checkbox of list) {
     checkbox.checked = true;
    };
    " in document 1

document 1
end tell
```